# Expression on Lightning Component not working on production

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I built a component that retrieves a list from the database and then iterate those items applying an attribute `onfilter` that defaults to `true` on each record.

Using this little CSS trick I'm able to show or hide elements that are on the filter:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
<tr style="{!item.onfilter == true ? '' : 'display: none;'}">
...
</tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

And it works just fine on Sandbox (Summer 17). But it fails on the production instance (Spring 17). Since no errors are displayed on production, I decided to do a little inspection, and found that every record is being loaded as expected, but the expression is being evaluated as `false` and thus every record is hidden on the list, even though when I check the console logs, I can see that they all have `onfilter` set to `true`.

Does anyone know if this is a bug that is being worked on?

## Edit (helper.js code)

This is what happens when I get the result from the database:

```
var items = response.getReturnValue();
items.forEach(function (item) {
    item.onfilter = true
})
component.set('v.items', items)
```

## Edit 2 (after problem was solved)

This seems to be an issue on instances that are not updated to Summer 17. I'm saying this because on sandbox I've updated the component's version to use API 40, and it is working just fine.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see the definition of the items list, but I think you need to declare all attributes in advance or at least set them all at once (the first time you set the list is when getters and setters are defined for the objects in it). So, define a default item in your list and make sure you include the `onFilter` attribute. It doesn't matter if it's false or true.

Comment: If this works, I'll make it an answer :) - it's hard to tell though at this point if I should.

Comment: So, when I get the records from the db I iterate them and set the attribute as `true`. It even works in one of the environments, like I said.

Comment: Yes, but does this attribute exist prior to this as a default - eg when you define your attribute in markup `default='[{"name":"something","onFilter":false}]'`

Comment: Hmm... Actually no. It is created and set right when I iterated the records after the database call. I'll update the original post.

Comment: Ok then - it's likely that because of LockerService, the terniary expression cannot see the value that you are setting. I'm going to make an answer because I think this is the issue.

Comment: You are right! LockerService was enabled on production! On sandbox it is applied rules for Summer 17 (only components created with API 40 or more have LS enabled by default).

Comment: Great! Let me know if my answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Locker Service in production is active, you are probably being tripped up by the absence of an implicit getter for the property that you are attempting to read in the iterator.

Define your items array (something) like this:

```
<aura:attribute 
      name="items" 
      type="Object[]" 
      default="[{'name':'something','onFilter':false}]"/>
```

This will allow Locker Service to create a getter and hence your object will be accessible

Comment: Just complementing your post: LockerService was indeed the cause of this issue. However, it was active on production because I activated the critical update, but it worked on sandbox because Locker Service is automatically applied to components created with API 40 or more only. Since my component was using API 36, it wasn't enabled on sandbox.

Comment: Ah great. I'll update the post to say that IF Locker Service is active...

Comment: On a side note, is there a way to create a getter without setting a default value for the component's attribute?

Comment: Hmm don't think so - since it's done by the framework, we have little control over it.